# STM32F4 How to get first message from Can1 and send it to Can2 , Can1 and Can2 have different speed

Tags: stm32, can-bus, keil, stm32f4discovery, bus

I have a development kit STM32f4 discovery kit and it has double Canbus interface modules. How to get first message from Can1 and send it to Can2 , Can1 and Can2 have different  speed

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from Your question is Your controller will read from CAN1 and write same message on CAN2.

In this case BaudRate should not be any problem. You will get data from CAN1 Rx Buffer and All you need to do is write same data in CAN2 Tx Buffer. CAN Controller will take care of BaudRates, You should not bother about it.